# String number with limited precision fraction digits in Swift

Tags: swift, string, precision, nsnumberformatter

What would be the fastest way to convert a `String` number "1234.5678" to an `NSNumber` with precision -> 1234.56 and back to `String` "1234.56".

```
let numberFormatter = NumberFormatter()
numberFormatter.maximumFractionDigits = 2
numberFormatter.string(from: numberFormatter.number(from: "1234.534234")!)
```

This code does not look that beautiful. Any ideas?

Comment: Not sure what is you question. Are you trying to discard the precision after the second fraction digit ?

Comment: I have a string number that can have several digits. In the end I want to convert it to a string that has a specific number of digits that I can set manually.

Comment: I would first use Decimal instead of NSNumber

Comment: Can you please be more concrete?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the new formatted method and specify the number of precision fraction length to two:

```
let decimal = Decimal(
    sign: .plus,
    exponent: -4,
    significand: 12345678
)  // 1234.5678
decimal.formatted(.number.precision(.fractionLength(2))) // "1,234.57"
decimal.formatted(.number.grouping(.never).precision(.fractionLength(2)))  // "1234.57"
decimal.formatted(.number.grouping(.never).rounded(rule: .towardZero).precision(.fractionLength(2)))  // "1234.56"
```

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively if you are only interested in the ***string*** regardless of any numeric modification like rounding you can strip the unwanted characters with Regular Expression

```
let string = "1234.5678"
let trimmedString = string.replacingOccurrences(of: "(\\d+\\.\\d{2})\\d.",
                                            with: "$1",
                                            options: .regularExpression)
```

Comment: Thanks for one more option!